# a question about clifford-algebras

Tags: clifford-algebras

in n -imensional linear space,e_i are the standard Orthogonal basic, we use the axiom of clifford algebra : $x\cdot y = \frac{1}{2}(xy+yx) ,x\wedge y = \frac{1}{2}(xy-yx), xy=x\cdot y + x\wedge y$ to deduce(i,j,k are not the same, so $e_i\cdot e_j = 0$ and so on) :
and we have $e_ie_j=-e_je_i$  so $e_ie_je_k=e_ke_ie_j$

$(e_i\wedge e_j)\cdot e_k = \\
(e_ie_j-e_i\cdot e_j)\cdot e_k = \\
(e_ie_j)\cdot e_k=\\
\frac{1}{2}(e_ie_je_k+e_ke_ie_j)=\\
e_ie_je_k = (e_i\wedge e_j)\cdot e_k + (e_i\wedge e_j)\wedge e_k \Rightarrow \\
e_i\wedge e_j\wedge e_k = 0$

but $e_i\wedge e_j\wedge e_k \neq 0$  ,so where is the problem??

Comment: The problem is that $e_ie_j$ is not a vector. The $xy$ formulas at the top are generally valid only when $x$ and $y$ are vectors.

Comment: but the first two equation at the top can deduce the xy formulas on top, so the first two equation are also just valid for x,y vectors?

Comment: Right. I was referring to all three of those formulas involving $xy$, not just the one formula $xy=x\cdot y+x\wedge y$.

Comment: that's fine , thank you

Comment: another quiz, so how can we define $/^$ for multi-vector?

Comment: You mean the wedge product? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra#Extensions_of_the_inner_and_exterior_products